# How to set the width of the website?

Tags: css, width, document-body

I have created a theme for the zen cart site but the site's  width is not setting from me.

There is a horizontal scrolling on the site.

Here is my site.
http://harleydragon.info

Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The style is not very good. You're including multiple css and redefining the body several times. 
[Read on how to write](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) a css and then give it a clean.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting width in percentage:

```
#wrapper { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    width:90% /* or you can also set 900px*/
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add(or modify) some css file?

If yes set

```
.your_website_class {
width: your_width px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body have these

```
width: 1500px;  // set appropriate width
height: 1600px; // remove this line
```

fix these.

Comment: I remove the height but still facing the same problem.

Comment: what about your width, is it still 1500px ?